# _.each and Collection.each error

Tags: backbone.js

I'm playing around with the [Todos example](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html)  for backbone.js, but the toggleAllComplete function is not iterating over the collection when I run save. However, when I instead alert the title, it iterates over the whole collection.

```
toggleAllComplete: function () {  
    var done = this.allCheckbox.checked;  
    Todos.each(function (todo) {  
        /* this doesn't iterate over the collection */  
        // todo.save({'done': done});  
        /* this does */      
        alert(todo.get('title'));  
    });  
}
```

Why?

I've also tried this with       `_.each(Todos.models, function(todo) {`  but the same problem persists. 
When I use developer tools in chrome, I see that I have an Uncaught Type Error: Converting circular structure to JSON on this line in backbone-localstorage.js

```
this.localStorage().setItem(this.name+"-"+model.id, JSON.stringify(model));
```

Comment: Works for me with the link you gave.  You don't see them all get checked when you click that?

Comment: It's on my locally hosted copy of the code, I downloaded the example off github...

Answer (score 0):

If there's an error saving, then it's probably stopping each from going over every model. When you do an alert, there's no error, so it lets each do its job.

You could try throwing in some callbacks on the save method to see if that helps you debug.

```
todo.save({'done': done}, {
  success: function() { console.log(["success", arguments]); } 
  error: function() { console.log(["error", arguments]); }
});
```